# Antlr4 CommonTokenStream Constructor

Tags: java, antlr4

I took a source code from ANTLR4 Doc site.

```
    JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
    JavaParser.CompilationUnitContext tree = parser.compilationUnit();// parse a compilationUnit
```

But 
        new CommonTokenStream(lexer) 
is problematic. Because **there is no constructor for new CommonTokenStream(lexer)**. There are constructors  new CommonTokenStream() and  new CommonTokenStream(TokenStream) but many examples in the internet use that constructor like given in the code which is Antlr4 Doc site's example. 
Also there is no constructor for JavaParser(CommonTokenStream).

Thanks

Comment: did you ensure that your parser/lexer is generated successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are constructors new CommonTokenStream() and new CommonTokenStream(TokenStream)

No, there 2 constructors in `CommonTokenStream`:

- `CommonTokenStream(TokenSource tokenSource)`
- `CommonTokenStream(TokenSource tokenSource, int channel)`

not the two you mention. See: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonTokenStream.html

> Because there is no constructor for new CommonTokenStream(lexer).

Every generated lexer extends ANTLR4's [`Lexer`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html) class, which implements [`TokenSource`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenSource.html), so doing `new CommonTokenStream(lexer)` will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. But i forgot that: 
'import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream'. Sorry

Comment: Actually, that was a confusion. Because I did 'import org.antlr.runtime.*;' and eclipse show me CommonTokenStream() automatically. But v4 was missed.

Comment: Ah, you had the old classes in your classpath, that explains it. Glad to hear you're up and running!